# Using pandas fillna() on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a new pandas user (as of yesterday), and have found it at times both convenient and frustrating.

My current frustration is in trying to use df.fillna() on multiple columns of a dataframe.  For example, I've got two sets of data (a newer set and an older set) which partially overlap.  For the cases where we have new data, I just use that, but I also want to use the older data if there isn't anything newer.  It seems I should be able to use fillna() to fill the newer columns with the older ones, but I'm having trouble getting that to work.

Attempt at a specific example:

```
df.ix[:,['newcolumn1','newcolumn2']].fillna(df.ix[:,['oldcolumn1','oldcolumn2']], inplace=True)
```

But this doesn't work as expected - numbers show up in the new columns that had been NaNs, but not the ones that were in the old columns (in fact, looking through the data, I have no idea where the numbers it picked came from, as they don't exist in either the new or old data anywhere).

Is there a way to fill in NaNs of specific columns in a DataFrame with vales from other specific columns of the DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: yes.  Look at using the `value` argument of fillna. Along with the `to_dict()` method on the other dataframe.

**But to really solve your problem**, have a look at the [`update()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas.DataFrame.update) method of the DataFrame.  Assuming your two dataframes are similarly indexed, I think it's exactly what you want.

```
In [36]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan, 5], 'B': [1, 0, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 1]})

In [37]: df
Out[37]: 
    A   B
0   0   1
1 NaN   0
2   2   1
3   3 NaN
4 NaN NaN
5   5   1

In [38]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]})

In [40]: df2
Out[40]: 
    A  B
0   0  1
1 NaN  0
2   2  1
3   3  1
4   4  0
5   5  0

In [52]: df.update(df2, overwrite=False)

In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
    A  B
0   0  1
1 NaN  0
2   2  1
3   3  1
4   4  0
5   5  1
```

Notice that all the `NaN`s in `df` were replaced except for `(1, A)` since that was also `NaN` in `df2`.  Also some of the values like `(5, B)` differed between `df` and `df2`.  By using `overwrite=False` it keeps the value from `df`.

EDIT: Based on comments it seems like your looking for a solution where the column names don't match over the two DataFrames (It'd be helpful if you posted sample data).  Let's try that, replacing column A with C and B with D.

```
In [33]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan, 5], 'B': [1, 0, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 1]})

In [34]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [0, np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'D': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]})

In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
    A   B
0   0   1
1 NaN   0
2   2   1
3   3 NaN
4 NaN NaN
5   5   1

In [36]: df2
Out[36]: 
    C  D
0   0  1
1 NaN  0
2   2  1
3   3  1
4   4  0
5   5  0

In [37]: d = {'A': df2.C, 'B': df2.D}  # pass this values in fillna

In [38]: df
Out[38]: 
    A   B
0   0   1
1 NaN   0
2   2   1
3   3 NaN
4 NaN NaN
5   5   1

In [40]: df.fillna(value=d)
Out[40]: 
    A  B
0   0  1
1 NaN  0
2   2  1
3   3  1
4   4  0
5   5  1
```

I think if you invest the time to learn pandas you'll hit fewer moments of frustration.  It's a massive library though, so it takes time.

Comment: I like this idea, but it seems to work only if the column names are the same - eg, if I change 'A' and 'B' from `df2` above to 'C' and 'D', this no longer works, even though the indexes (indices?) of the two dataframes are exactly the same.  (I think this is also why the `to_dict()` in the `value` of `fillna()` doesn't work - the returned dictionary has the column names as its keys.)

Comment: Are you saying that your column names aren't meaningful? You can make this work by (temporarily) renaming the columns of the old dataframe to use the new dataframe's column names; but I'm guessing there's a better way to store/process your data.  Maybe post some sample data and we can help!

Comment: They do have meaning.  I've got a workaround in just doing one column at a time (eg, `df.ix[:,'newcolumn1'].fillna(df.ix[:,'oldcolumn1'])`).  Given that this works while doing one column at a time, I'm surprised it doesn't work for the list of columns I wanted originally, but this seems to be becoming more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: See my edit.  That will work for you and should be more efficient that indexing.  Plus using `.ix` may run into issues with returning a view vs. copy.

Comment: That'll do it.  It's interesting to see the interplay between DataFrames and dicts.  Definitely something I'm going to have to play around with more as time goes on.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`fillna` is generally for carrying an observation forward or backward.  Instead, I'd use `np.where`... If I understand what you're asking.

```
import numpy as np
np.where(np.isnan(df['newcolumn1']), df['oldcolumn1'], df['newcolumn1'])
```