# How do I fill NA values in multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 50 columns. I want to replace NAs with 0 in 10 columns.

What's the simplest, most readable way of doing this?

I was hoping for something like:

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df[cols].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

But that gives me `ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only`.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000019/using-pandas-fillna-on-multiple-columns), but it's rather hard to understand.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use [update()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
In [145]: df
Out[145]:
    a   b   c  d  e
0 NaN NaN NaN  3  8
1 NaN NaN NaN  8  7
2 NaN NaN NaN  2  8
3 NaN NaN NaN  7  4
4 NaN NaN NaN  4  9
5 NaN NaN NaN  1  9
6 NaN NaN NaN  7  7
7 NaN NaN NaN  6  5
8 NaN NaN NaN  0  0
9 NaN NaN NaN  9  5

In [146]: df.update(df[['a','b','c']].fillna(0))

In [147]: df
Out[147]:
     a    b    c  d  e
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  3  8
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  8  7
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  2  8
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  7  4
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  4  9
5  0.0  0.0  0.0  1  9
6  0.0  0.0  0.0  7  7
7  0.0  0.0  0.0  6  5
8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0  0
9  0.0  0.0  0.0  9  5
```

Answer (score 11):

```
In [15]: cols= ['one', 'two']
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
        one       two     three four   five
a -0.343241  0.453029 -0.895119  bar  False
b       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN
c  0.839174  0.229781 -1.244124  bar   True
d       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN
e  1.300641 -1.797828  0.495313  bar   True
f -0.182505 -1.527464  0.712738  bar  False
g       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN
h  0.626568 -0.971003  1.192831  bar   True

In [17]: df[cols]=df[cols].fillna(0)

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
        one       two     three four   five
a -0.343241  0.453029 -0.895119  bar  False
b  0.000000  0.000000       NaN  NaN    NaN
c  0.839174  0.229781 -1.244124  bar   True
d  0.000000  0.000000       NaN  NaN    NaN
e  1.300641 -1.797828  0.495313  bar   True
f -0.182505 -1.527464  0.712738  bar  False
g  0.000000  0.000000       NaN  NaN    NaN
h  0.626568 -0.971003  1.192831  bar   True
```

Comment: I am voting this up, as it helped me with filling it up with mean as well.

Answer (score 3):

And a version using column slicing which might be useful in your case:

```
In [46]:
df

Out[46]:
    a   b   c   d   e
0   NaN NaN NaN 3   8
1   NaN NaN NaN 8   7
2   NaN NaN NaN 2   8
3   NaN NaN NaN 7   4
4   NaN NaN NaN 4   9
5   9   NaN NaN 1   9
6   NaN NaN NaN 7   7
7   NaN NaN NaN 6   5
8   NaN NaN NaN 0   0
9   NaN NaN NaN 9   5

In [47]:
df.loc[:,'a':'c'] = df.loc[:,'a':'c'].fillna(0)
df

Out[47]:
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   0   0   3   8
1   0   0   0   8   7
2   0   0   0   2   8
3   0   0   0   7   4
4   0   0   0   4   9
5   9   0   0   1   9
6   0   0   0   7   7
7   0   0   0   6   5
8   0   0   0   0   0
9   0   0   0   9   5
```